# Display products in HOT DEAL section of Home Page of Fastest Theme in Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9

I am using Fastest Theme. In Home Page I have to display products in Hot Deal section.

[image]

I got a Static Block in Admin panel.

[image]

I got below code in This Hot Deal Static Block.

```
<div class="cdz-products box-style06 space-base">
<div class="cdz-block-title">
<p class="h2"><span>Hot deal</span></p>
</div>
<div class="text-center box-content">{{widget type="filterproducts/codazonfilterproducts" categories="111" filtertype="5" orderby="name" order="asc" limit="8" thumb_width="220" thumb_height="220" use_ajax="1" custom_template="codazon_filterproducts/home_grid_style17.phtml" display="name,image,label,price,rating,description,addtocart_btn,wishlist_btn,compare_btn" use_slider="1" margin="-1" items_1280="1" items_1024="1" items_768="1" items_480="2" items_320="2" items_0="2" show_nav="1" cache_lifetime="1"}}</div>
</div>
```

I set `Yes` in Hot options of product.

[image]

But I can't see products in HOT DEAL section of Home Page.

Comment: I think it is only showing product form category id =111, it is nothing related to attribute.

Comment: Thanks @Pawan. I tried by changing `category id` but it is not working. Thanks.

Comment: pelase clear cache and try

Comment: or put the log to get the collection of product